# Draw shape on UIView using Beizepath?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

How to draw background paths like below images?

[image]

I am trying my self but safe not coming properly

Below My code:

```
public class ShapeView : UIView{
    public override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
        
        let corneRadius : CGFloat = 40.0

        //// Color Declarations
        let fillColor = UIColor(red: 0.125, green: 0.259, blue: 0.443, alpha: 1.000)
        let fillColor2 = UIColor(red: 0.153, green: 0.314, blue: 0.525, alpha: 1.000)

        //// g10
        //// g12
        //// path14 Drawing
        context.saveGState()
        context.translateBy(x: rect.origin.x, y: rect.origin.y)
//        context.rotate(by: 0.8 * CGFloat.pi/180)

        let path14Path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: rect.origin.x, y: rect.origin.y, width: rect.size.width, height: rect.size.height), cornerRadius: CGFloat(corneRadius))
        fillColor.setFill()
        path14Path.fill()

        context.restoreGState()


        //// g16
        //// g18
        //// g24
        //// path30 Drawing


        //// path32 Drawing
//        let path32Path = UIBezierPath()
//        path32Path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y:0))
////        path32Path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 5.15, y: corneRadius))
////        path32Path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: corneRadius + 5 , y: 0), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: corneRadius + 5 , y: corneRadius ), controlPoint2: CGPoint.zero)
////        path32Path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 50.59, y: 5.01), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 50.53, y: 5.01), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 50.56, y: 5.01))
//        path32Path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width * 0.3, y: 0))  // top left x and y position of first shape
//        path32Path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: rect.height * 0.5))
//        path32Path.close()
//        fillColor2.setFill()
//        path32Path.fill()
        
        
//        let path14Path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: -321.25, y: -190.1, width: 642.5, height: 380.2), cornerRadius: 44.6)

        
//        let path30Path = UIBezierPath()
//        path30Path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 182.31, y: 385.45))
//        path30Path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 45.15, y: 385.16))
//        path30Path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 17.03, y: 374.93), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 34.43, y: 385.13), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 24.65, y: 381.31))
//        path30Path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 329.68, y: 5.61))
//        path30Path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 503.55, y: 5.99))
//        path30Path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 182.31, y: 385.45))
//        path30Path.close()
//        fillColor2.setFill()
//        path30Path.fill()
        
        
        
        
        let path30Path = UIBezierPath()
        path30Path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width * 0.5, y: rect.height - 10))
        path30Path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 10, y: rect.height  -  10 ))
//        path30Path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: corneRadius , y: 374.93), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: rect.width * 0.5 * 2, y: 385.13), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: rect.width * 0.5, y: 381.31))
        
        path30Path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width * 0.8, y: 0))
        path30Path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width * 0.35, y: rect.height))
        path30Path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width * 0.5, y: rect.height ))

        path30Path.close()
        fillColor2.setFill()
        path30Path.fill()

        


        //// path34 Drawing
//        let path34Path = UIBezierPath()
//        path34Path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 283.03, y: 385.67))
//        path34Path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 208.2, y: 385.51))
//        path34Path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 529.44, y: 6.04))
//        path34Path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 603.49, y: 6.2))
//        path34Path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 604.26, y: 6.21), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 603.75, y: 6.2), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 604.01, y: 6.21))
//        path34Path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 283.03, y: 385.67))
//        path34Path.close()
//        fillColor2.setFill()
//        path34Path.fill()
//
//
//        //// path36 Drawing
//        let path36Path = UIBezierPath()
//        path36Path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 522.68, y: 386.19))
//        path36Path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 447.85, y: 386.03))
//        path36Path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 646.21, y: 151.71))
//        path36Path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 644.92, y: 241.79))
//        path36Path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 522.68, y: 386.19))
//        path36Path.close()
//        fillColor2.setFill()
//        path36Path.fill()
    }
}
```

I want to draw those background light color, shapes.

**Output:**

[image: Output Image]

Comment: Why don't you use `CAGradientLayer`?

Comment: what is the difference CAGradientLayer and Beizerpath? View height will be changed based on Screen height * 0.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your case, your shape is of regularity.

To handle the coordinates math, better to use a relevant list coordinates, based on the rect height.

```
public class ShapeView : UIView{
    public override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let list: [CGFloat] = [0, 0.5, 1, 1.6, 1.7, 2, 2.5, 2.7, 3]
        let coordinates = list.map { (i) -> CGFloat in
            rect.height * i
        }
        var i = 1
        let shallow = UIColor(red: 0.125, green: 0.259, blue: 0.443, alpha: 1.000)
        let deep = UIColor(red: 0.153, green: 0.314, blue: 0.525, alpha: 1.000)
        while i < list.count {
            let b = UIBezierPath()
            b.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: coordinates[i - 1]))
            b.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: coordinates[i]))
            b.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: coordinates[i], y: 0))
            b.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: coordinates[i - 1], y: 0))
            b.close()
            if i % 2 == 1{
                shallow.setFill()
            }
            else{
                deep.setFill()
            }
            b.fill()
            i += 1
        }
    }
}
```

To handle the corners left, u can use `layer.cornerRadius`

call like this:

```
  let v = ShapeView()
  v.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 100, width: 300, height: 150)
  v.layer.cornerRadius = 30
  v.clipsToBounds = true
  view.addSubview(v)
```

[image: 111]

Comment: my view size are based  Main screen width of 80% and height of 30%, this is not working if i set size to dynamic size

Comment: for dynamic size, you can redraw the canvas. just call `view.setNeedsDisplay()`

Comment: i created IBOutlet and called still not working.   override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [self] in
            creditCardVeiw.setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

Comment: this is not working . how it is not working. The desired image you posted has height width ratio 2 : 1.  I tried your Main screen width of 80% and height of 30% , on iPhone 
12 mini . The current width ratio  is 1.23 : 1.

Comment: As I tested, the above code is OK, if u keep your image on the height width ratio 2 : 1,  If your  image  height width ratio is dynamic, I can not image the effect you desire

Comment: suspecting about your given coordinates that should < 1 right?

Answer (score 2):

to improve @dengApro's nice answer.

Could use an other way to handle the corners,

just to draw corners, instead of using `layer.cornerRadius`

```
public class ShapeView : UIView{
    public override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

        let list: [CGFloat] = [0, 0.5, 1, 1.6, 1.7, 2, 2.5, 2.7, 3]
        let coordinates = list.map { (i) -> CGFloat in
            rect.height * i
        }
        var i = 1
        while i < list.count {
            let b = UIBezierPath()
            b.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: coordinates[i - 1]))
            b.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: coordinates[i]))
            b.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: coordinates[i], y: 0))
            b.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: coordinates[i - 1], y: 0))
            b.close()
            if i % 2 == 1{
                UIColor.blue.setFill()
            }
            else{
                UIColor.green.setFill()
            }
            b.fill()
            i += 1
        }
        
        
        // for corners
        let upLhs = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        let upRhs = CGPoint(x: rect.width, y: 0)
        let downRhs = CGPoint(x: rect.width, y: rect.height)
        let downLhs = CGPoint(x: 0, y: rect.height)
        let corner: CGFloat = 30
        let upLhsArc = UIBezierPath()
        upLhsArc.move(to: upLhs)
        upLhsArc.addLine(to: upLhs + .x(corner))
        upLhsArc.addArc(withCenter: upLhs ~> PointOffset(x: corner, y: corner), radius: corner, startAngle: .pi * 1.5, endAngle: .pi, clockwise: false)
        upLhsArc.close()
        
        let upRhsArc = UIBezierPath()
        upRhsArc.move(to: upRhs)
        upRhsArc.addLine(to: upRhs + .x(corner * -1))
        upRhsArc.addArc(withCenter: upRhs ~> PointOffset(x: corner * -1, y: corner), radius: corner, startAngle: .pi * -0.5, endAngle: 0, clockwise: true)
        upRhsArc.close()
        
        let downRhsArc = UIBezierPath()
        downRhsArc.move(to: downRhs)
        downRhsArc.addLine(to: downRhs + .x(corner * -1))
        downRhsArc.addArc(withCenter: downRhs ~> PointOffset(x: corner * -1, y: corner * -1), radius: corner, startAngle: .pi * 0.5, endAngle: 0, clockwise: false)
        downRhsArc.close()
        
        let downLhsArc = UIBezierPath()
        downLhsArc.move(to: downLhs)
        downLhsArc.addLine(to: downLhs + .x(corner))
        downLhsArc.addArc(withCenter: downLhs ~> PointOffset(x: corner , y: corner * -1), radius: corner, startAngle: .pi * 0.5, endAngle: .pi, clockwise: true)
        downLhsArc.close()
        // use your background color
        UIColor.white.setFill()
        upLhsArc.fill()
        upRhsArc.fill()
        downRhsArc.fill()
        downLhsArc.fill()
    }
}
```

call like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     let v = ShapeView()
     v.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 100, width: 300, height: 150)
     view.addSubview(v)
 }
```

[image: 777]

help functions:

```
struct PointOffset{
    let x: CGFloat
    let y: CGFloat
}


enum PointDimension{
    case x(CGFloat), y(CGFloat)
}


func +(left: CGPoint, right: PointDimension) -> CGPoint {
    switch right {
    case .x(let v):
        return CGPoint(x: left.x + v, y: left.y)
    case .y(let v):
        return CGPoint(x: left.x, y: left.y + v)
    }
}


infix operator ~>: AdditionPrecedence
func ~>(left: CGPoint, right: PointOffset) -> CGPoint{
    return CGPoint(x: left.x + right.x, y: left.y + right.y)
}
```

Comment: my view size are based Main screen width of 80% and height of 30%, this is not working if i set size to dynamic size

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to improve @dengApro's nice code.

**Do improvement in rendering performance.**

@dengApro's nice code, fills color on some extra place.

Then do some calculation to avoid the extra work.

```
// coordinates's structure

// [[CGPoint]], 
// an array of an array , the inner array has two points
// the first point is at top, the second point is at bottom
public class ShapeView : UIView{
    public override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let list: [CGFloat] = [0, 0.5, 1, 1.6, 1.7, 2, 2.5, 2.7, 3]
        let h = rect.height
        let coordinates = list.reduce([[CGPoint]]()) { (result, val) -> [[CGPoint]] in
            if result.isEmpty{
                return [[CGPoint(x: val, y: val), CGPoint(x: val, y: val)]]
            }
            else{
                let x = h * val
                let first = CGPoint(x: x, y: 0)
                let y = h * min(1, val)
                var secondX: CGFloat = 0
                if val > 1{
                    secondX = x - h
                }
                return result + [[first, CGPoint(x: secondX, y: y)]]
            }
            
        }
        
        var i = 1
        let shallow = UIColor(red: 0.125, green: 0.259, blue: 0.443, alpha: 1.000)
        let deep = UIColor(red: 0.153, green: 0.314, blue: 0.525, alpha: 1.000)
        while i < list.count {
            let b = UIBezierPath()
            b.move(to: coordinates[i-1][0])
            b.addLine(to: coordinates[i][0])
            b.addLine(to: coordinates[i][1])
            b.addLine(to: coordinates[i-1][1])
           // print(coordinates[i-1][0],  coordinates[i][0],  coordinates[i][1], coordinates[i-1][1])
            b.close()
            if i % 2 == 1{
                shallow.setFill()
            }
            else{
                deep.setFill()
            }
            b.fill()
            i += 1
        }
    }
}
```

call like this:

```
    let v = ShapeView()
    v.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 100, width: 300, height: 150)
    v.layer.cornerRadius = 30
    v.clipsToBounds = true
    view.addSubview(v)
```

[image: 888]

Comment: my view size are based Main screen width of 80% and height of 30%, this is not working if i set size to dynamic size

Comment: It is easy to replace the size based on rect  , with size based on the  Main screen . Just set the list with the coordinates in your mind . The important point is how u draw the lines

Answer (score 1):

improve @dengST30's code,

improve the point calculation reduce method:

```
public class ShapeView : UIView{
    public override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let list: [CGFloat] = [0.5, 1, 1.6, 1.7, 2, 2.5, 2.7, 3]
        let h = rect.height
        let start = [CGPoint](repeating: CGPoint.zero, count: 2)
        let points = list.reduce([start]) { (result, val) -> [[CGPoint]] in
            let x = h * val
            let y = h * min(1, val)
            var secondX: CGFloat = 0
            if val > 1{
                secondX = x - h
            }
            return result + [[CGPoint(x: x, y: 0), CGPoint(x: secondX, y: y)]]
        }
        var i = 1
        while i < points.count {
            let b = UIBezierPath()
            b.move(to: points[i-1][0])
            b.addLine(to: points[i][0])
            b.addLine(to: points[i][1])
            b.addLine(to: points[i-1][1])
            b.close()
            if i % 2 == 1{
                UIColor.black.setFill()
            }
            else{
                UIColor.lightText.setFill()
            }
            b.fill()
            i += 1
        }
    }
}
```

[image: 777]

Comment: my view size are based Main screen width of 80% and height of 30%, this is not working if i set size to dynamic size

Comment: It is easy to change. Maybe you should post an other question.